# Confusion matrix, false negative

Tags: matrices

I would like to know how to calculate the false negative, the true negative, the false positive and the true positive to form a confusion matrix. A numeric example would clear all doubts I think. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**True positives** are cases predicted positive which are actual positive

**False positives** are cases predicted positive which are actual negative (false alarms)

**False negatives** are cases predicted negative which are actual positive (missed cases)

**True negatives** are cases predicted negative which are actual negative

Just count these up and put them in your confusion matrix. If you want rates, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic#Basic_concept) has a concise description.

Answer (score 1):

You question may be ill-posed, but let me see if I can provide some thoughts.

Does this [**Example**](http://khartig.wordpress.com/tag/confusion-matrix-example/) work?

Matlab even has a [**Command**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/confusionmat.html) with  examples.

Regards -A

Answer (score 0):

I am posting my little cheat sheet that helps me remember easily. Every application has a structure it maintains in the calculation so you may want to check that out. This structure is from scikit-learn.

[You may watch this video to gain a deeper understanding.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Oog7TXHvFY)

[image]